# Using RegQueryInfoKey() to enumerate COM ports

Tags: winapi, registry

Trying to get the number of available comports.
Used the following code:

```
HKEY hKey;
if (RegOpenKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,TEXT("HARDWARE\\DEVICEMAP\\SERIALCOMM"),&hKey)==ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
  DWORD NumKeys;
  RegQueryInfoKey(hKey,NULL,NULL,NULL,&NumKeys,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);
}
```

For some reason NumKeys returns to be 0, while there are serial ports showing in the registry. It does enters the if (meaning no error with RegOpenKey).

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The port names listed there are *values*, not keys.  Use the lpcValues argument instead.